# I'm getting FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, swing, jtree, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting FileNotFoundException. The same function used at other place is working fine. Please tell me what is wrong with this code:

```
try {
    if (redFolder.isDirectory() && redFile.isFile()) {
        Functions.matched_file_names=new ArrayList<>();
        obj.compare_With_TreeFolder(redFile, redFolder);
        StringBuffer bfr=new StringBuffer();
        for(String item:Functions.matched_file_names)
            bfr.append(item+"\n");
        matchedfileTextArea.setText(bfr.toString());
     } else if(redFile.isFile() && redFolder.isFile()){
         compareTwoTextualFiles cttf=new compareTwoTextualFiles();
         matchedfileTextArea.setText(cttf.compareFiles(redFile, redFolder));
     }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select File First.");
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("ExceptionCaught. "+e.getMessage());
}
```

The `if` block is working fine but the `else if` block is giving this exception:

```
/Users/esna786/File2.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File2.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at compareTwoTextualFiles.compareFiles(compareTwoTextualFiles.java:27)
    at comparisonForm$1.valueChanged(comparisonForm.java:58)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2926)
    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3387)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:635)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1093)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:294)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:188)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1633)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2393)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:3609)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3548)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6522)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4530)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The `else if` part is calling this block of code:

```
try {
    // Create FileReader & Writer Objects.
    FileReader File1Reader = new FileReader(File1.toString());
    FileReader File2Reader = new FileReader(File2.toString());

    // Create Buffered Object.
    BufferedReader File1BufRdr = new BufferedReader(File1Reader);
    BufferedReader File2BufRdr = new BufferedReader(File2Reader);

    // Get the file contents into String Variables.
    String File1Content = File1BufRdr.readLine();
    String File2Content = File2BufRdr.readLine();

    //New String Builder
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    // Compare the Contents of the files.
    String startOfComparision = "---------START----------";
    buffer.append(startOfComparision).append("\n");

    boolean isDifferent = false;
    int lineNumber = 1;

    if (File1Content != null || File2Content != null) {

        // Check whether file1 contains data or not
        while ((File1Content != null)) {

            // Check whether file2 contains data or not
            if (((File2Content) != null)) {

                // Check whether both the files have same data in the lines
                if (!File1Content.equals(File2Content)) {
                    buffer.append("Difference in Line " + lineNumber + " :- " + File1.getName() + " contains :" + File1Content + "           " + File2.getName() + " Contains : " + File2Content).append("\n");
                    isDifferent = true;
                }
                lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
                File2Content = File2BufRdr.readLine();
            } else {
                buffer.append("Difference in Line " + lineNumber + " :- " + File1.getName() + " contains :" + File1Content + "             " + File2.getName() + " Contains - " + File2Content).append("\n");
                isDifferent = true;
                lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
            }

            File1Content = File1BufRdr.readLine();

        }

        // Check for the condition : if File2 has Data & File1 doesn't contain data.
        while ((File2Content != null) && (File1Content == null)) {
            buffer.append("Difference in Line " + lineNumber + " :- " + File1.getName() + " contains :" + File1Content + "           " + File2.getName() + " Contains - " + File2Content).append("\n");
            isDifferent = true;
            lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
            File2Content = File2BufRdr.readLine();
        }

    } else {
        // Mention that both the files don't have Data.
        buffer.append(File1.getName() + " and " + File2.getName() + " do not contain any data.");
        isDifferent = true;
    }

    // Check is there any difference or not.
    String endOfComparision = "-----------END----------";
    if (isDifferent) {
        buffer.append(endOfComparision).append("\n");
    } else {
        buffer.append("No Difference Found \nThe Contents Of The Files Are Identical.").append("\n");
        buffer.append(endOfComparision).append("\n");
        Functions.matched_file_names.add("Path: " + File2.getAbsolutePath() + "\nFile Name: " + File2.getName());

    }

    //Close the streams.
    File1Reader.close();
    File2Reader.close();
    File1BufRdr.close();
    File2BufRdr.close();

    float percentage = (float) (getCommonWords(File1, File2) / get_Total_Number_Of_Words(File1)) * 100;

    return buffer.toString() + " \n\nThe Total number of common words of " + File1.getName() + " and " + File2.getName() + " are: " + getCommonWords(File1, File2) + "\n\nThe " + File1.getName() + " is " + Math.ceil(percentage) + " % matched with " + File2.getName() + ".";
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select Files." + e.getMessage());
}

return null;
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: This is hard to read. Also, did you double check that the path exists? The file exists? The spelling is correct?

Comment: yes i checked it using filename.getabsolutepath.

Comment: chceck whether path or file exist because its simple FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the [path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getPath()). Check if that's the location you were expecting the file to be in.

Comment: put comment not answer :)

Comment: I tried printing the path using filename.getabsolutepath. it is still not working

Comment: Try (exists)[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()]. If it returns false, then there is definitely no file or equivalent (Eg: file/directory permissions).

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved it byreplacing the above code as:

```
try {
    // Create FileReader & Writer Objects.
    FileReader File1Reader = new FileReader(File1.getAbsolutePath());
    FileReader File2Reader = new FileReader(File2.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: It's simple because the error cleanly states only the name of the file, you need a complete path of the file not a name. Glad that you resolved by yourself, so that you will never stuck here again.